# Add 30 days to date

Tags: php

Hello all i am trying to add 30 days to my date. I am using below coding.

```
<?php
$next_due_date = date('05/06/2016', strtotime("+30 days"));
echo $next_due_date;
?>
```

But it is returning to "05/06/2016" only!

Please help me!

Comment: @chris85 - At date('d/m/Y') it is working perfectly as its adding 30 days in todays date

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please try this.

```
echo date('m/d/Y',strtotime('+30 days',strtotime('05/06/2016'))) . PHP_EOL;
```

This will return `06/06/2016`. Am assuming your initial date was in m/d/Y format. If not, fret not and use this.

```
echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime('+30 days',strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '05/06/2016')))) . PHP_EOL;
```

This will give you the date in d/m/Y format while also assuming your initial date was in d/m/Y format. Returns `05/07/2016`

If the input date is going to be in mysql, you can perform this function on mysql directly, like this.

```
DATE_ADD(due_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Comment: well i am fetching date from mysql

$next_due_date = date('d/m/Y',strtotime('+30 days',strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '$userRow3["due_date"]')))) . PHP_EOL;

And this is returning - 31/01/1970

Comment: If you are using mysql, then use the first function. mysql dates are of the format yyyy-mm-dd. The first one will work fine for that. Just change the format in the beginning appropriately to either m/d/Y or d/m/Y.

Comment: i am fetching date from MYSQL and want to add 30 days in it.. check below code if it is right:-

<?php
$next_due_date = date('y-m-d',strtotime('+30 days',strtotime('echo $userRow3["due_date"]'))) . PHP_EOL;
?>

Comment: You dont need an echo there, nor the PHP_EOL. Just use 

`<?php $next_due_date = date('y-m-d',strtotime('+30 days',strtotime($userRow3["due_date"]))) ; ?>`

Comment: @Rahul so only now you mention mysql, makes a difference, you can do it with a mysql function instead.

Comment: Yes doing this in mysql is the way to go. I have updated my answer. @Rahul, you might want to try this approach as well.

Answer (score 47):

Do **not** use php's date() function, it's not as accurate as the below solution and furthermore it is unreliable in the future.

Use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2016-06-06'); // Y-m-d
$date->add(new DateInterval('P30D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```

The reason you should avoid anything to do with UNIX timestamps (`time()`, `date()`, `strtotime()` etc) is that they will inevitably break in the year [2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) due to integer limitations.

The maximum value of an integer is `2147483647` which converts to `Tuesday, 19 January 2038 03:14:07` so come this time; this minute; this second; everything breaks

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

Another example of why I stick to using DateTime is that it's actually able to calculate months correctly regardless of what the current date is:

```
$now = strtotime('31 December 2019');

for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    echo date('d M y', strtotime('-' . $i .' month', $now)) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

You'd get the following sequence of dates:

```
31 December
31 November
31 October
31 September
31 August
31 July
31 June
```

PHP conveniently recognises that three of these dates are illegal and converts them into its best guess, leaving you with:

```
01 Dec 19
31 Oct 19
01 Oct 19
31 Aug 19
31 Jul 19
01 Jul 19
```

Comment: The best answer here.

Comment: Why is/was date() inaccurate and unreliable?

Comment: @Torben see update

Comment: excellent explanation

Answer (score 18):

The first parameter is the format, not the current date.

```
<?php
$next_due_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+30 days"));
echo $next_due_date;
```

Demo: https://eval.in/583697

If you want to add the `30 days` to a particular starting date use the second parameter of the `strtotime` function to tell it where to start.

When in doubt about how a function works refer to the manual.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: <?php
$next_due_date = date('06/05/2016', strtotime("+30 days"));
echo $next_due_date;

This is not working

Comment: @Rahul Yes, that is what you previously had. What is `06/05/2016`, that looks like today/yesterdays date. The `strtotime` will start at the current date by default if the second parameter is empty.

Comment: @Rahul don't use `"06/05/2016"`, use `"d/m/Y"` like @chris85 said!

Comment: but then it will add 30days to todays date!! i want to add 30 days to my own date

Comment: @Rahul so you didn't read my answer, or the supplied link? Specifically from the link `The timestamp which is used as a base for the calculation of relative dates.` Specifically from my answer, `particular starting date use the second parameter of the strtotime function to tell it where to start.`.

Comment: @chris - i am fetching date from MYSQL and want to add 30 days in it.. check below code if it is right:-

<?php
$next_due_date = date('y-m-d',strtotime('+30 days',strtotime('echo $userRow3["due_date"]'))) . PHP_EOL;
?>

Comment: Don't do `echo` it is suppose to be the exact date string. Just `$userRow3["due_date"]'` in the `strtotime`.

Answer (score 10):

You need to provide date format like `d/m/Y` instead of `05/06/2016`

Try

```
$old_date = '05-06-2016';
$next_due_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($old_date. ' +30 days'));
echo $next_due_date;
```

Comment: But i don't want today's date.... i have a stored date i want to add in it!

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Ok well your is pretty good!

Comment: Actually the OP had date in d/m/Y or m/d/Y format (Its ambiguous). This answer will not work if the format was d/m/Y. Please check my answer which will work for both.

Answer (score 3):

```
$date = "1998-08-14";
$newdate = strtotime ( '30 day' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
$newdate = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $newdate );

echo $newdate;
```

[Found the above code](http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/php-adding-and-subtracting-dates/)

Comment: Not working for format - d/m/Y